# Bash while loop between two times

Tags: linux, bash, opensuse

I am trying to write a bash script that will loop if the time is after certain time and before a certain time. Here is what i have got but it gives me an error;

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ date +"%T" -gt '06:00:00' && date +"%T" -lt '21:00:00'];
  do
  ##echo `php mainstatquery.php`
  echo "Hello World";
  sleep 5;
done
```

and this is the error

```
./timer.sh: line 3: [: missing `]'
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an easy way to understand your `while` problems:

The `[` is an actual Unix command. Do `ls /bin/[` and you'll see. It's a link to the `/bin/test` command. Do a `man test` from the command line and see the various *tests* that can be done.

What the `while` does is execute the command you give it, and if it returns a zero exit status, the `while` statement is considered true and the statement will continue. You can do things like this:

```
while sleep 2
do
   echo "I slept for two seconds"
done
```

All the `test` command does is do some sort of testing (file tests, tests of equality, etc.) and return a zero if the statement is true and a non-zero otherwise:

```
$  test 2 -gt 3
$ echo $?
1   <- That statement is false

$ [ 2 -lt 3 ]   #The test command using square brackets
$ echo $?
0  <- That statement is true.
```

Take a look at the manpage for `test` and you'll see all valid tests. This:

```
while [ date +"%T" -gt '06:00:00' && date +"%T" -lt '21:00:00']
```

is the same as

```
while test date +"%T" -gt '06:00:00' && date +"%T" -lt '21:00:00'
```

Let's go through a few things here:

- date + %T is not a valid operator for the `test` command.

The `test` command can't execute a command internally. What you need to do is to put that command in `$(..)` and probably use quotes to play it safe. Thus:

```
while test "$(date +"%T")" -gt '06:00:00' && "$(date +"%T")" -lt '21:00:00'
```

- The `&&` is not a valid operator in the `test` command. What you probably want is `-a` which is the *and* conjunctive for stringing together two tests in `test`.

This would give you:

```
while test $(date +"%T") -gt '06:00:00' -a "$(date +"%T")" -lt '21:00:00'
```

- There are two separate *greater than* test operators for comparisons. One is for strings and one is for integers. The `-gt` is the test for integers. Since you're dealing with strings, you need to use `>`:

  while test "$(date +"%T")" > '06:00:00' -a "$(date +"%T")" < '21:00:00'

As an alternative, you could have also used the `&&` conjunctive instead of `-a`, but each side of the `&&` would have to be separate test statements:

```
while test "$(date +"%T")" > '06:00:00' && test "$(date +"%T")" < '21:00:00'
```

Now, let's convert the `test` syntax back to `[...]` because it's easier on the eyes

```
while [ "$(date +"%T")" > '06:00:00' -a "$(date +"%T")" < '21:00:00' ]
```

OR

```
while [ "$(date +"%T")" > '06:00:00' ] && [ "$(date +"%T")" < '21:00:00' ]
```

By the way, the internal `[[...]]` is better -- especially with the `>` sign since it can be interpreted by the shell as a file redirect.

```
while [[ "$(date +"%T")" > '06:00:00' -a "$(date +"%T")" < '21:00:00' ]]
```

OR

```
while [[ "$(date +"%T")" > '06:00:00' ]] && [[ "$(date +"%T")" < '21:00:00' ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare an entire hour like that.

As you are just checking the hour (6<=x<=21), use `date "+%H"` to do that:

```
while [ $(date +"%H") -gt 06 ] && [ $(date +"%H") -lt 21 ];
  do
  ##echo `php mainstatquery.php`
  echo "Hello World";
  sleep 5;
done
```

Also take into consideration that the `date` expression has to be called with `$()` to make it get the result. And your

```
while [  date +"%T" -gt '06:00:00'   &&      date +"%T" -lt '21:00:00'];
       $(        )                ]  &&  [  $(        )              ^ need space
```

Finally, the logical condition is not well written. The best [POSIX recommended](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/test.html#tag_04_140_16) way is:

```
if [ -f $VAR1 ] && [ -f $VAR2 ] && [ -f $VAR3 ]
```

Comment: Stringwise comparison of arbitrary times should work just fine as long as they're in the `%T` format with leading zeros added to single-digit hours.

Comment: It does not. If you try the OP code put correctly `while [ $(date +"%T") -gt "06:00:00" ] && [ $(date +"%T") -lt "21:00:00" ];`  you get a `./a: line 3: [: 00:12:27: integer expression expected`

Comment: You're right of course... I was influenced by the original code into seeing `-lt` as a string comparison, which it isn't. If you want to compare `%T`'s you'll need something less portable like `[[ $(date +%T) > 06:00:00 ]]`

Comment: Good point! I didn't think it would work: `$ if [[ $(date +%T) < 06:00:00 ]]; then echo yes; fi
yes`. Such an interesting behaviour, nice to know @WumpusQ.Wumbley

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only care about the hour so:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $(date +"%k") -gt 6 -a $(date +"%k") -lt 21 ];
do
  ##echo `php mainstatquery.php`
  echo "Hello World";
  sleep 5;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The `]` that closes a `[` command must be a separate argument. Put a space before it.